# C# console input

Tags: c#, linq, console

I'm having problems with my console input.
Code is:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Training
{
    static void Main()
   {
       double[] arr = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(double.Parse).ToArray();
       int[] roundedNums = new int[arr.Length];
       for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
       {
           roundedNums[i] = (int)Math.Round(arr[i], MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < roundedNums.Length; i++)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", arr[i], roundedNums[i]);
       }
   }
}
```

When i start the program i get an exception if i use . instead of , (example: if I type 3.5 i get an error, but if I type 3,5 the program works fine).
I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015.

How can i solve this?

Comment: what exception do you get?

Comment: You're running in a Culture different to English. Some culutres only ','  char as a decimal separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code to use specific culture. For example invariant culture, which would then treat `'.'` as a decimal separator and `','` as group separator.

You can apply `InvariantCulture` as such:

```
double[] arr = Console.ReadLine()
               .Split(' ')
               .Select(x => double.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
               .ToArray();
```

Some of the cultures default a space (`' '`) as decimal or group separators and `'.'` or `','` is interpreted as invalid input.

You can look up your separators used by default with two properties:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
```

Comment: @ognyan Type Region in start search > Advanced settings... and you can choose what separators to use for your default culture. You can also use properties mentioned in the answer to override your current threads culture settings. For example: `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";`

Answer (score 0):

replace this :

```
double[] arr = Console.ReadLine().Split('.').Select(double.Parse).ToArray();
```

with your this line :

```
double[] arr = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(double.Parse).ToArray();
```

Is it working ? let me know. :)

Comment: This is really wrong :-) The split stand for to let user to enter multiple values not for spliting a single value

Comment: @CodeNotFound okey sir. then i misunderstood his Question . my apology